# Connect multiple MySql db's to application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to connect multiple mysql db in my spring boot application. The thing is in my application, one of the db is used as an entity while from other db, I am fetching data in query form. So I want that whenever I write a custom query, it should take from one db while whenever I use repository methods, it should use another one.

Comment: One [reference example](https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-multiple-database-configuration)

Answer (score 2):

Change your application.properties file as :

```
#first db
spring.datasource.url = [url]
spring.datasource.username = [username]
spring.datasource.password = [password]
spring.datasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

#second db ...
spring.secondDatasource.url = [url]
spring.secondDatasource.username = [username]
spring.secondDatasource.password = [password]
spring.secondDatasource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

And Change your Configuration file i.e add following beans :

```
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.secondDatasource")
public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
   return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Comment: I am using activiti. So when I tried this, tables from activiti got created in the second db.

Comment: and how will I specify that my entity should use which db and for query which db?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases which describes the same what you are looking for